# Magento: possible to use ajax to query product API for specific range of IDs or subcategory?

Tags: ajax, magento

Wondering if I can use the Magento AJAX API (Magento v1.9.2.4) to query products using some basic (or not so basic) filters.

I'm trying to implement a custom 'load-more-on-scroll' feature for a product page. Anytime they scroll down, it should ask the API for new products that have an ID greater than 'previous_id', and possibly targeting a specific category or subcategory.

I've been looking around, but it's not apparent how to do this, and I'm rather new to Magento. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Where you are trying to do this. On a Product page or category page ?

Comment: On a category listing page. There's a page which lists some main categories at the top, then below it has each category broken out... each with any number of configurable products to begin (let's say 6 items). Then, when scrolling to the bottom of the page, I want to send an ajax request asking magento to give me products within each subcategory which are less than (ie. older) than the last product ID used. So just need to ask magento: "Can I have products for category A where ID < X", and then "Products for category B where ID < Y", etc...

Comment: Yeah, this is possible. You just need to create custom module. And create a controller in it that will handle your custom request. Have a look at this : https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/create-a-controller-tutorial.html

Comment: So, Send a AJAX request to your custom controller. Pass suitable parameters like category ID, Product ID. And then in the controller you will have to add some business logic to grab the Product collection from the DB. Wrap them in HTML and in response pass HTML as JSON.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if I needed custom module+controller. I thought maybe the built-in products API could be used, but perhaps not. The tutorial you sent seems way simpler than a lot of the others I've been reading. Thank you Robin!

Comment: Welcome ! Happy Coding :)